# Unity3D Ball only shoots right with swipe

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Alright so I have it working to where the ball is thrown, and if I swipe right it'll go in that direction, however that's the only direction it will go.
If I swipe up, or anywhere left on the screen the ball still gets thrown to the right. So my question is, what can I change in my code to make it swipe in the direction I'm swiping?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {

    }

    private float length = 0;
    private bool SW = false;
    private Vector3 final;
    private Vector3 startpos;
    private Vector3 endpos;

    public GameObject basketball; //Basketball Obj
    public Rigidbody rbody;// Basketball Obj

    public float Force = 0.2f;

    void Update()
    {
        rbody = basketball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            final = Vector3.zero;
            length = 0;
            SW = false;
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            startpos = new Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, 0, touchDeltaPosition.y);
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            SW = true;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            SW = false;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            SW = false;
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (SW)
            {
                Vector2 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                endpos = new Vector3(touchPosition.x, 0, touchPosition.y);
                final = endpos - startpos;
                length = final.magnitude;
                rbody.AddForce(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.x + touchPosition.y, touchPosition.y) * Force);
            }
        }
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(50, 300, 500, 30), "length: " + length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `TouchPhase.Ended` condition, try replacing

`rbody.AddForce(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.x + touchPosition.y, touchPosition.y) * Force);`

with this:

`fin = fin.normalized;
rbody.AddForce(fin * Force);`

This might solve your problem.

Comment: Force isn't applied at all now.

Comment: Once try to log the `startPos` and `endPos` values just to check if you are receiving the right values. And add `SW = false` below the `AddForce()` function also change the variable name `final` to some other like `fin`.

Comment: I used the GUI to track the start and end pos, they're both updating as I swipe across the entire screen.

Comment: Try to increase the value of `Force` to some `20.0f` as we are normalizing the values, I guess, increasing the value of `Force` would do the thing

Comment: Still not registering the left side of the screen.
I've tried rbody.AddRelativeForce(finpos * Force, ForceMode.Force);
As-well with no success.

Renamed final to finpos.